# How to disable certain enforcer rules in a child module in a multi-module maven project?

Tags: java, maven, java-8, maven-3, maven-enforcer-plugin

I am using a maven-enforcer plugin in a multi-module maven project. Let's say my project structure is like below

```
main
  - query
  - storage
```

My enforcer plugin in `main` pom looks like below

```
<build>
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <DependencyConvergence/>
                                <requireJavaVersion>
                                    <version>[1.8,)</version>
                                    <message>*** This project requires JDK 1.8/J2SE 8 or later. ***</message>
                                </requireJavaVersion>
                            </rules>
                            <fail>true</fail>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
</builds>
```

In a child module (`query`) if I need to disable one of the enforcer rules (let's say `DependencyConvergence`) can someone let me know how can this be done?

Maven Version - 3.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also answered in the [maven mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/ra33823d451191885eb2b2cda266fbb7cd42f4cffaace3853f333b6ee%40%3Cusers.maven.apache.org%3E).

> So something like the following if all configuration is managed via a
> pluginMangement section;
>
> ```
> <build><pluginManagement><plugins>
>   <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>     <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
>     <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
>     <executions>
>       <execution>
>         <id>alpha</id>
>         <phase></phase>
>         <goals>
>           <goal>enforce</goal>
>         </goals>
>         <configuration>
>           <rules>
>             <DependencyConvergence/>
>             <requireJavaVersion>
>               <version>[1.8,)</version>
>               <message>*** This project requires
> JDK 1.8/J2SE 8 or later. ***</message>
>             </requireJavaVersion>
>           </rules>
>           <fail>true</fail>
>         </configuration>
>       </execution>
>       <execution>
>         <id>bravo</id>
>         <phase></phase>
>         <goals>
>           <goal>enforce</goal>
>         </goals>
>         <configuration>
>           <rules>
>             <requireJavaVersion>
>               <version>[1.8,)</version>
>               <message>*** This project requires
> JDK 1.8/J2SE 8 or later. ***</message>
>             </requireJavaVersion>
>           </rules>
>           <fail>true</fail>
>         </configuration>
>       </execution>
>     </executions>
>   </plugin>
> <plugins>
>   <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>     <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
>     <executions>
>       <execution>
>         <id>alpha</id>
>         <phase>validate</phase>
>       </execution>
>     </executions>
>   </plugin>
> </plugins></builds>
> ```
>
> `query/pom.xml`
>
> ```
> <build><plugins>
>   <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>     <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
>     <executions>
>       <execution>
>         <id>alpha</id>
>         <phase></phase>
>       </execution>
>       <execution>
>         <id>bravo</id>
>         <phase>validate</phase>
>       </execution>
>     </executions>
>   </plugin>
>     </executions>
>   </plugin>
> </plugins></builds>
> ```
>
> you might also be able to do it via a property and in query define the
> bravo execution instead of the alpha. I've used a similar technique
> with maven-surefire-plugin, where i define the plugin version using a
> property and have a default in the root/parent pom, and in one
> specific child pom i define a different surefire version. so this
> might work...
>
> ```
> <build><pluginManagement><plugins>
>   <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>     <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
>     <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
>     <executions>
>       <execution>
>         <id>alpha</id>
>         <phase></phase>
>         <goals>
>           <goal>enforce</goal>
>         </goals>
>         <configuration>
>           <rules>
>             <DependencyConvergence/>
>             <requireJavaVersion>
>               <version>[1.8,)</version>
>               <message>*** This project requires
> JDK 1.8/J2SE 8 or later. ***</message>
>             </requireJavaVersion>
>           </rules>
>           <fail>true</fail>
>         </configuration>
>       </execution>
>       <execution>
>         <id>bravo</id>
>         <phase></phase>
>         <goals>
>           <goal>enforce</goal>
>         </goals>
>         <configuration>
>           <rules>
>             <requireJavaVersion>
>               <version>[1.8,)</version>
>               <message>*** This project requires
> JDK 1.8/J2SE 8 or later. ***</message>
>             </requireJavaVersion>
>           </rules>
>           <fail>true</fail>
>         </configuration>
>       </execution>
>     </executions>
>   </plugin>
> <plugins>
>   <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>     <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
>     <executions>
>       <execution>
>         <id>${which-enforcer-id}</id>
>         <phase>validate</phase>
>       </execution>
>     </executions>
>   </plugin>
> </plugins></builds>
> <properties>
>   <which-enforcer-id>alpha</which-enforcer-id>
> </properties>
> ```
>
> `query/pom.xml`
>
> ```
> <properties>
>   <which-enforcer-id>bravo</which-enforcer-id>
> </properties>
> ```
>
> John

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you cannot disable a single enforcer rule.

You can set `enforcer.skip` to `true` -- this disables *all* enforcer rules.

What I have done in a similar situation:

I have defined my own enforcer rule which inherited from an "official" enforcer rule. This enforcer rule contained a switch to disable it.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html explains how to write a custom rule. If I am using a custom `property` in the child pom any suggestion how can I read that property value from the pom into the rule class ?